# Amazon itemsearch api - PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

I am developing an amazon product search application using PHP. Currently it returns 5 items. But I need only 1 item to be returned.

Is there a amazon itemsearch query to control the results returned to 1?

I use `SearchIndex` as `blended` and as an example I am using `SanDisk Ultra 16GB High Speed USB 3.0 Flash Drive` as the `keyword` and `"Operation"   => "ItemSearch"`

full query

```
 $parameters = array("Operation"   => "ItemSearch",
                        "Keywords"    => $keyword,
                        "SearchIndex" => $product_type);
```